# Question about version specific resource file

Tags: android, android-resources, android-styles

My application support up to the sdk version 21, but I have some styles that work only for SDK 23+.

Should I only add a SDK 21 specific styles.xml, or should I also add a SDK 22 specific styles.xml ? Because they share the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you just need a general styles file, and a 23+ styles.  Then anything below 23 will use the general file, and anything 23 or higher will use the v23 one.